# Reduce Redirect chain by replacing all spaces once with hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i am using this htaccess code to replace spaces and + sign with hyphen

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=301]`

but the problem is if there 5 spaces or + in the url it will redirect 5 times

so how to make it redirect only once

and if there is not a solution for this
how to redirect this url

`/search/articles?search_query=تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة arab arab تجربة تجرب تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة arab تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة تجربة&t=t&o=mr`

to the main page

Comment: You’d have to make this an internal redirect instead, and have that loop (`N` flag) as long as there are still characters to replace to be found. Only after that, you do an external redirect to the current URL then. But you’d have to find a way to figure out if _any_ replacement happened in the first place - otherwise you’d just be redirecting to the exact same URL, and thereby create a loop.

Comment: (This would by a bit easier to handle using whatever back-end scripting language you have available, instead of doing the replacing part with mod_rewrite - there you’re likely to have string replace functionality available that can handle this all in one go, and doesn’t have to do it one character at a time.)

Comment: i don't have experience in back-end and i search for for php code to replace all spaces and + and didn't find it
anyway this htaccess code is working fine beside this problem
i tried to add N in the code but it doesn't work i think there are another code should be modified , can u give me the final code ?